# How do I implement a while loop to this function

Tags: c++

I am working on a school project where we will make a contact book. In one of the functions, it must find contacts using the first name.

The error that occurs is that it only shows one contact in the vector. I want all contacts with the same name to be displayed.

How do I implement a loop or counter (i++) so that it includes all contacts with the same name and not just take the first index?

Im new to C++ and appreciate all help :)

My function:

```cpp
int findTargetFirstName(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok, string target) {
  for (int i = 0; i < bok.size(); i++)
    if (bok[i].fnamn == target) return i;
  return -1;

void search(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok) {
  if (bok.size() > 0) {
    string firstname;
    cout << "First name of the contact: ";
    getline(cin, firstname);
    int pos = findTargetFirstName(bok, firstname); 
    cout << "Firstname, Lastname, Address, Pnummer, E-post, Telefonnummer" << endl;
    if (pos>=0) {
      cout << left;
      cout << setw(10) << bok[pos].fnamn << left
           << setw(15) << bok[pos].enamn << left
           << setw(20) << bok[pos].adress << left
           << setw(15) << bok[pos].pnummer <<left
           << setw(25) << bok[pos].epost <<left
           << setw(15) << bok[pos].telnummer << left << endl;
    }
    cout << "********************************************************************************" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning when the first result, add it to a std::vector and return the whole vector after the for loop

Comment: you seem to know `std::vector` so one possible first step would be to make `findTargetFirstName` return a `vector` of indices instead of only the first match, alternatively make it start to search from some `startIndex` and call it repeatedly

Comment: Proper indentation would make it easier for people to want to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is adding a parameter to determine which element to start from.

```
int findTargetFirstName(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok, string target, int start = 0) {
    for (int i = start; i < bok.size(); i++)
        if (bok[i].fnamn == target) return i;
    return -1;
}


void search(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok) {
    if(bok.size() > 0) {
        string firstname;
        cout << "First name of the contact: ";
        getline(cin, firstname);
        int pos = findTargetFirstName(bok, firstname);
        cout << "Firstname, Lastname, Address, Pnummer, E-post, Telefonnummer" << endl;
        while (pos>=0){ // change if to while
            cout << left;
            cout << setw(10) << bok[pos].fnamn << left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].enamn << left
            << setw(20) << bok[pos].adress << left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].pnummer <<left
            << setw(25) << bok[pos].epost <<left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].telnummer << left << endl;
            pos = findTargetFirstName(bok, firstname, pos + 1); // search for next contact
        }
        cout << "********************************************************************************" << endl;
    }
}
```

Another way is having the function `findTargetFirstName` return a vector of contacts that meets the condition.

```
vector<int> findTargetFirstName(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok, string target) {
    vector<int> ret;
    for (int i = start; i < bok.size(); i++)
        if (bok[i].fnamn == target) ret.push_back(i);
    return ret;
}


void search(vector<Kontaktbok>& bok) {
    if(bok.size() > 0) {
        string firstname;
        cout << "First name of the contact: ";
        getline(cin, firstname);
        vector<int> poses = findTargetFirstName(bok, firstname); // change type and variable
        cout << "Firstname, Lastname, Address, Pnummer, E-post, Telefonnummer" << endl;
        for (int pos : poses){ // change if to range-based for
            cout << left;
            cout << setw(10) << bok[pos].fnamn << left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].enamn << left
            << setw(20) << bok[pos].adress << left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].pnummer <<left
            << setw(25) << bok[pos].epost <<left
            << setw(15) << bok[pos].telnummer << left << endl;
        }
        cout << "********************************************************************************" << endl;
    }
}
```